# WSO2 CEP and SQL Server insert into with primary keys set on the SQL Server side

Tags: sql-server, wso2, siddhi, wso2-cep

I have a database on SQL Server with a table that has the following structure:

```
ID has IDENTITY set to true.
```

When i go into the WSO2 CEP and try to make a stream dump its events into the table i am getting the following error:

```
from MessageStream
insert into msg;

Error while dispatching events: Error while adding events to event table, Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'EDS_MSG' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

org.wso2.siddhi.core.exception.ExecutionPlanRuntimeException: Error while adding events to event table, Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'EDS_MSG' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

Is there a way using SiddhiQL to not send the ID and let SQL Server to handle that **primary key** with **auto increment**?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `ID int` from the `define table msg`? I'm not familiar with `SiddhiQL`, so I'm just guessing.

Comment: I haven't tried it. I have the same problem. i never connected wso2 with sql server before either. i'll try it.

Comment: You mention you have the identity set to true but do you mean that identity_insert is set to on? These are two different things.

Comment: @RichBenner i dont want to set it to on. i want sql server to manage the auto increment not me on the application side

Comment: @JoaoFilipeClementeMartins then totally ignore that column, don't try to insert anything into it. In your query just pretend it isn't there and it'll auto increment upon insert.

Comment: @WEI_DBA i did that and it works. Thanks make that an answer and i'll accept it

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the `ID int` from the `define table msg`.

```
@From(eventtable='rdbms', datasource.name='WSO2_TRX_DB', table.name='EDS_MSG')
define table msg (Descri string, StartDate long, EndDate long, UpdateDate long, LastUser string);

from MessageStream
insert into msg;
```